# Angular Ui Router not loading view when accessing url [material-ui + tabs]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I'm using Angular + [material-ui](https://material.angularjs.org/) and basically I want to do an onboarding process with different steps so I'm using the tabs directive , each with a different `ui-view`.

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="TabsCtrl" class="content" ng-show="$root.loadingComplete">
    <md-tabs md-selected="$root.selectedIndex" md-border-bottom class="md-primary">
        <md-tab id="tab1" md-on-select="goTo('start')">
            <md-tab-label>Welcome</md-tab-label>
            <md-tab-template>
                <md-content>
                    <div ui-view="vStart"></div>
                </md-content>
            </md-tab-template>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab id="tab2" md-on-select="goTo('personal')">
            <md-tab-label>Personal</md-tab-label>
            <md-tab-template>
                <md-content>
                    <div ui-view="vPersonal"></div>
                </md-content>
            </md-tab-template>
        </md-tab>
```

This is my routes config:

```
angular.module('onboarding').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('start', {
                url: '/:memberId',
                views: {
                    vStart: {
                        templateUrl: 'views/start.html',
                        controller: 'StartCtrl'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('personal', {
                url: '/:memberId/personal',
                views: {
                    vPersonal: {
                        templateUrl: 'views/personal.html',
                        controller: 'PersonalCtrl'
                    }
                }
            })
           ...
```

The function goTo(status):

```
$scope.goTo = function(state) {
            $state.transitionTo(state, $stateParams);
        };
```

The problem is mainly that if I open the "home" at url `localhost:9000/#/12345` it's working fine, I see the start view and I can switch to the personal view with

```
$rootScope.selectedIndex = 1;
$state.transitionTo('personal', $stateParams);
```

But if I open the url straight from `localhost:9000/#/12345/personal` nothing is happening, the view is not loaded and also the controller is not loaded.
I have a `console.log('start controller')` and same `console.log('personal controller')` to check when they are loaded.

Also the browser history is not working, for example I go to the start page `locahost:9000/#/12345` and then click on the button to go to  `localhost:9000/#/12345/personal` everything is all right but then if I go back with browser history the url is `localhost:9000/#/1245` (correct) but the view is totally empty and no controller loaded at all.

Comment: Any chance you can set up a Plunkr or CodePen to recreate this issue. I currently use ui router with md-tabs and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: I gave up at some point and changed the code, maybe it was just that release I was using (0.8.3 if I remember correctly) that had a problem. I'll try next week the latest version :)

Comment: don't give up! :) I have tried the same version. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your routing is off. UI-router appends the substate's url to its parent state.

Try removing the heading `/:memberId`:

```
.state('personal', {
    url: '/personal',
        views: {
            vPersonal: {
                templateUrl: 'views/personal.html',
                controller: 'PersonalCtrl'
             }
         }
})
```